# Mixed Content in SplitterPane

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, html-helper, splitter

What is the correct/cleanest syntax for specifying a mixture of content within a KendoUI `SplitterPane`?

***Additional Information:***

I'm using a `Splitter` in KendoUI and I sometimes have the need to declare a combination of plain html markup alongside various custom `HtmlHelpers` within a `SplitterPane`. e.g.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Splitter()
              .Name("main-container")
              .Panes(panes =>
              { 
                  panes.Add().Content(
                      @<text>
                          @Html.CustomHelpers().SomeCustomHelper()
                          <div>This is some markup</div>
                          @Html.CustomHelpers().AnotherCustomHelper() 
                      </text>   
                  );
              }))
```

I'm currently using the `@<text>` Razor syntax, however it doesn't feel very clean. Are there any better alternatives that I may be overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the cleanest way - another option which I personally do not suggest is:

```
          panes.Add().Content(Html.CustomHelpers().SomeCustomHelper().ToHtmlString() +
                      "<div>This is some markup</div>" +
                      Html.CustomHelpers().AnotherCustomHelper() .ToHtmlString()

              );
```

Basically if you use Html helpers and partial views properly you reach the limitation which does not allow you to insert nested @ tags.